Prove that $\|f\|=n^{1/2} $
We define
$$B(X,Y)= \{ f \mid f:X \to Y, \text{ is continuous and linear function}\}$$
We said that $f$  is linear bounded function if $$ \exists M>0 : \forall x\in X, \|f(x)\| \le M\|x\| $$
Also, we define this norm on $B(X,Y)$
$\|f\|:= \inf \{M>0 \mid \forall x\in X, \|f(x)\| \le M\|x\| \}$
let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$
$f(x)= \sum_{k=1}^n x_k $,
($x= (x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$)
Here we use this norm on $\mathbb R^n : \|x\|=(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2)^{1/2} $
I proved that f is linear. Also it's continuous because it is linear bounded function.
( $ \forall x\in X, \|f(x)\| =|\sum_{k=1}^n x_k | \le \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k| \le m. (\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2 x)^{1/2}=\|x\| $ )
Because $ \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|$ and $(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2 )^{1/2}$ are equal norms.
Now I try to prove that $\|f\|=n^{1/2} $
it's clear that
$$ \forall k=1,2,...,n ; (\max \{x_k | k=1,2,...,n \})^2 \ge |x_k|^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2 \le \sum_{k=1}^n  (\max \{x_k | k=1,2,...,n \})^2$$
$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2 \le n (\max \{x_k | k=1,2,...,n \})^2$$
$$ \Rightarrow (\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2)^{1/2} \le n^{1/2} \max \{x_k | k=1,2,...,n \} $$
Also, it's clear that
forall k=1,2,...,n
$\max \{x_k | k=1,2,...,n \} \le \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|$
Then
$$ (\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2)^{1/2} \le n^{1/2} \max \{x_k | k=1,2,...,n \} \le n^{1/2} \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k| $$
$\Rightarrow  \|f(x)\| =|\sum_{k=1}^n x_k | \le \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k| \le n^{1/2}. (\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2 )^{1/2}=\|x\|$
So form the definition of infimum $ \|f\| \le n^{1/2} $
But how I can show that $ \|f\| = n^{1/2} $

Are you sure that the norm isn't $(\sum_k x_k^2)^{\frac12}$? Because then you'd have your $n^{\frac12}$. As it stands, you are right that it would be $1$.

@BrunoB I am sorry. You are write. I edited my question

Hint: you could have done this in a simpler fashion with Cauchy-Schwarz, and then you'd be able to use the equality case of Cauchy-Schwarz to try to guess what you could use to bound the norm from above.

This question's quite hard to read between too many logical connectives ($\forall,\exists,\Rightarrow$ should all be using sparingly and probably never) and bad Latex markup. There is markup for other operators: \max ($\max$) and \inf ($\inf$). Include all math symbols in math mode (between the $ signs) instead of the variables and curly braces you left outside. Use { and } for braces. Use $0$ not o for the number $0$. If you want to typeset many lines, like your enormous multi-line block of equations and connectives in the middle, use math display mode using 2 dollar signs open & close.

Suppose $M > 0$ satisfies $\|f(x)\| \le M\|x\|$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$. Then, $$M \ge \frac{\|f(x)\|}{\|x\|},$$
for every $x\in \Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$. Choose $x = (1,1,\ldots, 1)$ to get $$M \ge \frac{\|f(1,1,\ldots, 1)\|}{\|(1,1,\ldots, 1)\|} = \frac{n}{\sqrt n} = \sqrt n.$$
Thus, $$M\ge \sqrt n,$$
and taking infimums, $$\|f\| \ge \sqrt n.$$
The other direction follows from your work, so $\|f\| = \sqrt n$.

Thank you very much

Can you look for my solution above? I think I did a mistake and Now I can not prove that $|f| \le \sqrt n $
